# Does a PHP function exist where I can transform a number into a smaller string?

Tags: php

Lets say I have a function named `transform` and I run the following:

`echo transform(1);`
Would output "a"

`echo transform(26);`
Would output "z"

`echo transform(27);`
Would output "A"

`echo transform(345345);`
Would output a string combined with both letters (upper and lower case) and numbers that is shorter than 6 characters.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: Hexadecimal representation ? For what do you need this? (If you want a short answer: no!)

Comment: You could use base 36. That will use digits from 0 to 9 and letters A to Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use a base conversion.

```
<?php

function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
{
    if ($fromBaseInput==$toBaseInput) return $numberInput;
    $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput,1);
    $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput,1);
    $number = str_split($numberInput,1);
    $fromLen=strlen($fromBaseInput);
    $toLen=strlen($toBaseInput);
    $numberLen=strlen($numberInput);
    $retval='';
    if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789')
    {
        $retval=0;
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $numberLen; $i++)
            $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i-1], $fromBase),bcpow($fromLen,$numberLen-$i)));
        return $retval;
    }
    if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789')
        $base10=convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
    else
        $base10 = $numberInput;
    if ($base10<strlen($toBaseInput))
        return $toBase[$base10];
    while($base10 != '0')
    {
        $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10,$toLen)].$retval;
        $base10 = bcdiv($base10,$toLen,0);
    }
    return $retval;
}

echo convBase('345345','0123456789','0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789');
?>
```

Comment: Good think you didn't run your own code: `Warning: base_convert(): Invalid \`to base' (62)`

Comment: Exactly what I was after...  Thank you.

Comment: @user2255196 If my answer is exactly what you want, consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry, not used to this site.  Does clicking the "tick" hence making it go green count as an acceptance?